# WebDriver не находит нужный элемент

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Получаю http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
при поиске элемента следующим образом:
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='div']/font")).click();

Код страницы:

```
<a onclick="jdeWebGUIdoToggleSubMenu(this,'HE0_60hc_Form_Exit', event, true);">
<div class="WebLabel" id="div" style=" text-align: left;  overflow:hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap;" title="Форма (F) (Ctrl+Alt+F)">
<font class="FieldLabelSmall">Форма (<u>F</u>)</font>
</div>
</a>
```

Нажать нужно на слово "Форма", либо "F".

Comment: данного кода недостаточно ,чтобы понять в чем причина. пожалуйста, приложите к телу вопроса [необходимое количество кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
и, скорее всего, вы не ждете загрузки страницы или появления этого элемента

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код корректный, но не работал т.к. искомый элемент был в другом фрейме.
driver.switchTo().frame("frameName") исправил ситуацию.